# Field design problem for approval level + assigned user entity reference

Tags: 9

Say I have an approval system that needs to assign to users by levels with a limit of 5 levels

(say choose limit as 2 levels, then level 1 => uid 3, level 2 => uid4, that makes it a two level approval node).

Which setup of backend field is better on a decoupled system?

1. Create a single entity reference field, use the delta weight as level for the user being referenced within.
2. Create two field (integer list field + entity reference field), use integer list field as level and entity reference field for user.
3. A combined field to depict both integer list and entity reference field by each row (similar to paragraphs, but without layers of revisions control).

I feel like the second approach will be more straight forward and clean to handle with while the first approach is a twist of smart backend coding. But that may be a technical debt in the future?

Which is a better approach and why?